# What does SIFT do?

Tags: image, image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision, sift

What does SIFT do? does it establish the feature correspondences between views? Does it receive the corners of the image sand remove the ones which are not descriptive? Does it do the matching?

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform

Comment: Consider to read David Lowe's 2004 paper on SIFT (the most complete one by Lowe, the author of SIFT). http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/B:VISI.0000029664.99615.94

Comment: That's true but I wanted to have a better view before I have to read the entire paper. So is SIFT a replacement for NCC or SAD?

Comment: @C graphics That one you may post as another question. Try to be as specific as you can. This one was very basic (ie. able to be answered by google/wikipedia lurking). Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIFT is a short cut for "Scale Invariant Feature Transform".
SIFT features are often used to locate descriptive points in images.
For [image stitching](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/~brown/autostitch/autostitch.html) SIFT features are located in two images. Then you look for similar points / features in both images. If enough correspondences are found and the images contain some common part.

SIFT features have a location in an image, in addition the feature contains a rough description of nearby area of the image (the size of this area depends on the scale).
This description is used test if two SIFT features are describing the same location.

Comment: So can we say instead of NCC or ZNCC we can use SIFT? So is SIFT a replacement for NCC and ZNCC for matching?